# Open sets have open pre images means countinuity confusion

Tags: general-topology

Rudin 4.8 states

**4.8 Theorem** $\ $ *A mapping f of a metric space X into a metric space Y is continuous on X if an only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in X for every open set V in Y*

> **Proof** $\ $ Suppose $f$ is continuous on X and V is an open set in Y. We have to show that every point of $f^{-1}(V)$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}(V)$. So, suppose $p \in X$ and $f(p) \in V$. Since $V$ is open, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $y \in V$ if $d_Y(f(p),y)<\epsilon$; and since $f$ is continuous at $p$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$ if $d_X(x,p)<\delta$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ as soon as $d_x(x,p)<\delta$.

I understand this part and I believe that this part was discussed in another question. But I don’t understand the converse.

> Conversely, suppose $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$. Fix $p\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, let $V$ be the set of all $y\in Y$ such that $d_Y(y,f(p))<\epsilon$. Then $V$ is open; hence $f^{-1}(V)$ is open; hence there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ as soon as $d_X(p,x)<\delta$. But if $x\in f^{-1}(V)$, then $f(x)\in V$, so that $d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$.

Why is $V$ open? For V to be open there just has to exist one epsilon and it is probably not aribitary. Why did Rudin pick the epsilon first and then decided $V$ was open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a metric space (with the topology induced by the metric) the open sets are exactly given by unions of open balls. The set $V$ is just the open ball with radius $\epsilon$ around $f(p)$ and therefore open.